# Get remote directory size via SFTP

Tags: linux, openssh, sftp

I would like to get the size of a remote directory using SFTP.
Locally I would run `du -sh`, but my OpenSSH `sftp` client does not have that option.
I would like to point out that I do not have SSH shell access, so any connections with `ssh user@server` will be dropped.

Any ideas? Maybe scripting a solution? For example I could imagine listing all remote files using `ls -l` in my SFTP session, but I would have to parse the output and traverse through all subdirectories. I am also open to using a different client than OpenSSH.

Both server and client are running Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) uses the SFTP subsystem. This is a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)-based solution, get familiar with [security concerns](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/%7Epfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/security.html). You can (and should) do the mounting as a normal user:

```
sshfs user@server:some/path /some/local/mountpoint/
```

Then use `du -sh` locally. If the path of the directory you want is `some/path/foo/directory` on the remote system, then you need to use `/some/local/mountpoint/foo/directory`:

```
du -sh /some/local/mountpoint/foo/directory
```

To unmount:

```
fusermount -u /some/local/mountpoint/
```

Note: In the above example `some/path` is a relative path, relative to whatever remote directory SFTP initially uses as `./` for you. The string `./` itself (or `.` or an empty string) can be used to mount this exact directory. An absolute path can be used as well (e.g. `/bar/baz/dir`).