# How to use sftp 'ls' command to find all files in subdirectories including files beginning with '.'

Tags: linux, bash, sftp, globbing

I need to obtain a list of files contained within subdirectories including filenames starting with '.' using the `sftp ls` command. For example my directory structure on the remote is:

```
root_folder
    |
    + folder_1
    |   +.ready
    |
    + folder_2
    |
    + folder_3
        +.ready
        +my_tar.tar
```

From the root folder I can issue the command `ls -1 */*` which gives me:

```
folder3/my_tar.tar
```

If I include the `-a` e.g. `ls -1a */*` option I get the same result as above i.e. the hidden files are not listed.

By using `ls -1a */.*` I do see the hidden files but not 'normal' ones:

```
folder1/../
folder1/./
folder1/.ready
folder2/../
folder2/./
folder2/.ready
folder3/../
folder3/./
folder3/.ready
```

Interestingly it seems that it is the `*/.*` that causes the hidden files to be listed and not the `-a` switch.
Is there a way or globbing pattern that will list all the files with one command?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Consider [FUSE](https://superuser.com/a/1591651/432690). Then use `find` or whatever local command that fits your needs.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That's a good answer as I will have access to much better bash commands rather than those in sftp. I assume there should be no compatibility issues - I only ask as the remote site I'm connecting to is not under my control - I'll try it and see.

Comment: Indeed, the `-a` switch has no effect when a glob mask is used. It might be a bug. Consider [reporting it](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/enter_bug.cgi). If you do `ls -a` or `ls -a subdir/` it shows the hidden files.