# Cannot mount SFTP URL on local FileSystem using curlftpfs

Tags: filesystems, mount, sftp, curlftpfs

```
curlftpfs -o allow_other -o ssl -o no_verify_hostname -o no_verify_peer -o ftp_port=22 -o user='{{ ftp_user }}:{{ ftp_pass }}' {{ ftp_URL }} /mnt/sftp/
```

output is

> Error connecting to ftp: Access denied: 530

When the same credentials are used on the FileZilla app everything works fine.

What is wrong with the command above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`curlftpfs`](https://superuser.com/a/1292278/432690) "talks" FTP(S). [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) is not [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol). SFTP uses SSH. [`sshfs`](https://superuser.com/a/1591651/432690) "talks" SSH.

You mentioned SFTP and the port is 22 (the standard port for SSH), so most likely you need `sshfs`, not `curlftpfs`.